# Give folder full access when created

Tags: vb.net

I have a situation, I have a windows app that will create folders on a server if it does not exists and then I will copy a file to it but currently I get access denied on the specified path. This is what I have.

```
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(sdPath & "\DONE")) Then
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sdPath & "\DONE")
   sdFileInfo.MoveTo(sdPath & "\DONE\" & sdFileName & sdFileInfo.Extension)
Else
   sdFileInfo.MoveTo(sdPath & "\DONE\" & sdFileName & sdFileInfo.Extension)
End If
```

How can I give Full access to?

I have this piece of test code to see if I can get the permissions but doesn't seem to work.

```
txtPath.Text = "\\ServerName\images\dbpics\POLPICS\55\Polpics\Actual\"

Dim sFolderPath As String = txtPath.Text
Dim sUserAccount As String = "(DomainName\Administrator)"

Dim oFolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(sFolderPath)
Dim oFolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity(txtPath.Text, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.Access)

oFolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(sUserAccount, _
                                                  FileSystemRights.FullControl, _
                                                  AccessControlType.Allow))

oFolderInfo.SetAccessControl(oFolderAcl)

oFolderAcl = Nothing
oFolderInfo = Nothing
enter code here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
Imports System.Security.AccessControl


 Dim FolderPath As String = "C:\TestingFolder" 'Specify the folder here
 Dim UserAccount As String = "MYDOMAIN\someuser" 'Specify the user here

 Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
 Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
 FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.Modify,      InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow))
'FolderAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection(True, False) 'uncomment to remove existing permissions
FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)
```

I got it from this [URL](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?616021-Setting-file-and-folder-permissions)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the security you want to the directory creating it with:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sFolderPath, dirSecurity)
```

You can see some permissions and examples in the documentation of the [CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb.aspx) and the [DirectorySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx) of MSDN.