# Visual Basic .NET Access to the path 'C:\' is denied

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, access-denied, permission-denied

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Basic .NET to build the application (with Windows 7)

I currently build the install package and i install to another pc to test program.

When I was creating txt file by my app, i was getting "Access to the path  'C:\'  is denied" error

I know that I was using sub account to run my application.

If I run as administrator, it is was working fine.  However, the program should be able to run application without using administrator account .

These are what I tried to solve this problem so far.

**First**, I change the location to write file in "Program file folder" such as  "C:\Program file\My App"

However, it didn't work

**Second**, I was trying to change

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

at app.config

However, After I replaced to "requireAdministrator" , I am getting compiling error

```
ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'.  WindowsApplication2
```

**Third**, I went to Computer->manager->service-> and Enable Application experience.

However, it does not work.

I am not really sure what to do for this problem.

Does anybody know any solution ?

thanks

Comment: The program files folder and C:\ are both admin-only. The user-specific folder live under the user appdata folder (that's eg where Chrome installs). In short, a user who isn't an admin shouldn't be able to make changes that are system-wide, only to their own profile

Comment: Basic// Thanks for answering my question. Do you think , I can write file on the public folder ?? (without administrator permission)

Comment: You should be able to write to any public folders. To get special folders, look into using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` (Obviously, [look through the options for folders you can locate automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)) `SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments` or `SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` might also be useful. Make sure you don't assume you know where a folder will be - eg my Program Files folders are on my `D:` drive

Comment: You say you are building an install package (which implies .msi) but you appear to be using ClickOnce. ClickOnce apps will only run as standard user and are not installed in Program Files, but deep within the user's profile.  I think you need to clarify what you are trying to do and then choose the appropriate deployment method.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim UserAccount As String = "<user here>" 'Specify the user here
Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo("path")
Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow))
FolderAcl.SetAccessRuleProtection(False, False)
FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)
```

Note you have to add: Imports.System.Security.AccessControl

By the way I got it from here: [Give folder full access when created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853105/give-folder-full-access-when-) so credit goes to that person. (Jacques Bronkhorst) Hope this solves the issue :)