# How to create folder which is not readonly

Tags: vb.net

Following code creates readonly folder in the Temp folder.

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path:=IO.Path.GetTempPath & "Myfolder")
```

`directorySecurity:=` part of following code need to repaired

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path:=IO.Path.GetTempPath & "Myfolder", directorySecurity:=I need help here)
```

So, how to create folder which is not readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReadOnly` is an attribute, not a security option. Though creating a folder shouldn't make it read-only by default...

To remove the `ReadOnly` attribute you can create an instance of the [**`DirectoryInfo` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and modify its [**`Attributes` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx). I also strongly recommend that you use [**`Path.Combine()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) when constructing paths.

```
Dim DirPath As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Myfolder")
Directory.CreateDirectory(DirPath)

Dim Dir As New DirectoryInfo(DirPath)
Dir.Attributes = Dir.Attributes And Not FileAttributes.ReadOnly 'Bitwise removal.
```

Comment: @KenKeniee : That's odd... Is the TEMP folder set to read-only? What happens if you run your application with administrative privileges?

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853105/give-folder-full-access-when-created?rq=1